# Cloning git repo with all refs

Tags: git, mirror

I'm trying to get all refs from an external repository when cloning. I exported them all before, by doing `push --mirror`, so the external repository should have them, as far as I know.

How can I force all refs to be pulled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git fetch --tags
```

should be enough to get all branches, and all tags from your remote mirror bare repo.

```
-t
--tags
```

> Most of the tags are fetched automatically as branch heads are downloaded, **but tags that do not point at objects reachable from the branch heads that are being tracked will not be fetched by this mechanism**.
>   This flag lets all tags and their associated objects be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for this. It appears that I had a problem because not all refs were really pushed.